# Populating List from SQlite

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Good Tutorial for SQLite and ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685027/good-tutorial-for-sqlite-and-listview)

I am trying to populate ListView from SQLite. What should I do at ?????? in code. Do I need to build a String[] OR is there any better solution ?

```
Cursor cursor = assignment.numOfNewTask(empid);
        String[] sb = null;
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {    
                for(int i=0; i<cursor.getCount(); i++){
            ?????   sb [i]= "\"" + cursor.getString(0) + "\",";
                }
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());

        }


    list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list); 
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { 

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View v, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                //startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), TaskDetail.class));
            } 
        }); 
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listitem, sb);
        list.setAdapter(adapter2);


        linear.addView(text);
        setContentView(linear);
```

Comment: Do you intend for the `ListView` to show each item as `"...",`?

Comment: no. I was trying to build a string[]

Comment: Before that I was trying to build a String so just left it there.

Answer (score 4):

Try looking at how `SimpleCursorAdapter` is used in the [code here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NotePad/src/com/example/android/notepad/NotesList.html).

Answer (score 0):

You've set sb to null and then tried to assign to its elements. This will crash.

Use an `ArrayList<String>` instead, populating it with calls to `sb.add(cursor.getString(0))`. I'm pretty sure you don't need to wrap it in quotes and delimiters. `ArrayAdapter<String>` is perfectly happy with a `List<String>`.

**EDIT:** @MisterSquonks answer trumps mine.